# Upstream Repository vs Release Repository

Tags: bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I could not figure this out from the tutorials (http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseCatkinPackage & http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease), and I wanted to clarify this: if I *commit* something to the upstream repository, does this also update the release repository? Or do I have to release a new version each time I make a change?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209343/upstream-repository-vs-release-repository/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2015-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> if I commit something to the upstream repository, does this also update the release repository?

No. The upstream and release repository are separate repositories that have no direct (physical) relationship.

> do I have to release a new version each time I make a change?

Well, no. You don't *have to*. It depends on what you find 'release worthy'. Releases typically group a bunch of changes.

I guess you could say that releases are somewhat of a convenience for your users: if every change was followed by an immediate release, your users could just as well clone your development repository (I'm obviously ignoring things like packaging and installation, compatibility guarantees, etc).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-05-16**:
So, that means that the release repository is only updated when you do a **bloom-release**, right?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-16**:
yes. Obviously you can also manually modify your release repository, but in typical *ROS-ified* interaction, only `bloom` and its scripts do something with it.